# Sortable using 2 parameters javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using `sortable` for sorting some entries. It works fine with simple position numbers and when drag and drop any entry i can update those position number and display accordingly. But my problem is when user drags any entry I also want to update another parameter which is time.

I have created [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zjhez393/) here so that you can have more idea of my problem.

Initially it looks like this which is fine

[image]

But when I drag any entries it only updates the position number and not the time. I want the time to be updated as well.

[image]

Comment: You should be able to simply call `calculateTime` again whenever the list changes. If you refactor a bit, you can make it work nicely, but even without refactoring it should work.

Comment: @AlexCorreiaSantos i thought of that but the problem with `calculateTime` is that it takes values from the input box so if user assigns time once and clears the input field and than drag any entries that it will break.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Alex, you should just call calculateTime again. The only change is rather than grabbing the data from input again, you can store the input in an variable and grab the data from that variable.

```
//Here you set the stored variable
var stored_starttime, stored_minuteperround;

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#timing").click(
    function() {
      //Here you set the value of the stored variable
      stored_starttime = document.getElementById("stime").value;
      stored_minuteperround = document.getElementById("rounds").value;
      calculatetime(stored_starttime, stored_minuteperround);
    }
  );
});

$("#sortable_nav").sortable({
  placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
  helper: 'clone',
  sort: function(e, ui) {
    $(ui.placeholder).html(Number($("#sortable_nav > li:visible").index(ui.placeholder)) + 1);
  },
  update: function(event, ui) {
    var $lis = $(this).children('li');
    $lis.each(function() {
      var $li = $(this);
      var newVal = $(this).index() + 1;
      $(this).children('.sortable-number').html(newVal);
      //Here you check if the stored variables are defined
      if (stored_starttime !== undefined && stored_minuteperround !== undefined){
        calculatetime(stored_starttime, stored_minuteperround);
      }

    });
  }
});
$("#sortable_nav").disableSelection();
```

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zjhez393/5/

Comment: looks like a good plan and it will also work but i am gonna save those time values in database so when user comes back to same page and drag any entries than the page wont have any `stored_starttime ` or any `stored_minuteperround `.